# How to associate an uploaded file with signed url to the original request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a cloud function that generates a signed url for user's request, and another function that processes the uploaded file and updates the database.

I'm not sure how to associate the uploaded file to the original request.

---

So, the first function

1. receives a request containing a `userId`.
2. generates a `requestId` and the `signedUrl`
3. records the `requestId` in a database for the `userId`
4. sends the `signedUrl` to the client

A second cloud function is triggered when the file is uploaded. How can this function associate the uploaded file to the `requestId` generate in the first function?

I thought of 2 approaches, but both feel wrong to me:

**1.**
Encode the `requestId` into the file name. ⇒ This feels brittle as it relies on naming convention.

**2.**
Rely on the client. Pass the `requestId` with the `signedUrl` to the client. The client notifies when file is uploaded. ⇒ this just has too many failure points

Is there a proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention thing seems fine. An alternative might be to include a mandatory bit of [custom object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata) in the signed URL. For example, include this header in your signature:

```
x-goog-meta-my-request-id:someRequestId
```

That would require that the user uploading the object set that header, which will cause the object to have the custom metadata value "my-request-id" set to "someRequestId". That value will then be visible in the object metadata sent along with the object finalized message.

Comment: Interesting... So, would that require the client to set this specific header and the correct value `someRequestId`?

Comment: Yes, this only works if you are also writing the client and are able to set arbitrary headers.